# Function of sum of two expressions

Tags: function-construction, parametric-functions

I am trying to write a function to simplify some expressions for me, such as this:

```
f[u___+v___]:= f[u] + f[v]
```

However `f[a+b]` returns `f[] + f[a,b]`, whereas I want it to return `f[a] + f[b]`. But the same syntax works for `f[u___-v___]:= f[u] - f[v]` and `f[a-b]` returns `f[a] - f[b]`.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Your pattern allows for both `u` and `v` to be empty. I think you have one underscore too many. Compare [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) and [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html).

Answer (score 4):

It would be simply this:

```
f[u_ + v_] := f[u] + f[v]

f[a + b]
(* f[a] + f[b] *)
```